# Unable to resolve dependency package problem

Tags: system-installation, software-installation

```
WEB06160739D:~$ sudo apt-get install aptitude
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 aptitude : Depends: aptitude-common (= 0.6.11-1ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libcwidget3 but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: aptitude-doc-en but it is not going to be installed or
                        aptitude-doc
 dnsmasq-base : Depends: libdbus-1-3 (>= 1.9.14) but 1.8.12-1ubuntu5 is to be installed
                Depends: libhogweed4 but it is not installable
                Depends: libnettle6 but it is not installable
 gimp : Depends: libdbus-1-3 (>= 1.9.14) but 1.8.12-1ubuntu5 is to be installed
        Depends: libgegl-0.3-0 (>= 0.3.0) but it is not installable
 libarchive13 : Depends: libnettle6 but it is not installable
 libgd3 : Depends: libvpx2 (>= 1.4.0) but it is not installable
 libimobiledevice4 : Depends: libplist3 (>= 1.11) but it is not installable
                     Depends: libtasn1-6 (>= 4.3-0) but 4.2-2ubuntu1.1 is to be installed
 liboxideqt-qmlplugin : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-4-2 but it is not installable
 liboxideqtcore0 : Depends: libdbus-1-3 (>= 1.9.14) but 1.8.12-1ubuntu5 is to be installed
                   Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 5.2) but 4.9.2-10ubuntu13 is to be installed
 libpurple0 : Depends: libdbus-1-3 (>= 1.9.14) but 1.8.12-1ubuntu5 is to be installed
              Depends: libfarstream-0.2-5 (>= 0.1.91) but it is not installable
              Depends: perl-base (>= 5.20.2-6ubuntu0.2) but 5.20.2-2ubuntu0.1 is to be installed
 libreoffice-base-core : Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:5.0.6-0ubuntu1) but 1:4.4.6~rc3-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
                         Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 5) but 4.9.2-10ubuntu13 is to be installed
 libreoffice-calc : Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:5.0.6-0ubuntu1) but 1:4.4.6~rc3-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
                    Depends: libetonyek-0.1-1 (>= 0.1) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libicu55 (>= 55.1-1~) but it is not installable
                    Depends: libmwaw-0.3-3v5 but it is not installable
                    Depends: libodfgen-0.1-1v5 but it is not installable
                    Depends: liborcus-0.10-0v5 (>= 0.9.2-3ubuntu3) but it is not installable
                    Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 5.2) but 4.9.2-10ubuntu13 is to be installed
                    Depends: libwps-0.4-4 but it is not installable
 libreoffice-common : Breaks: libreoffice-style-galaxy (>= 1:4.5~) but 1:5.0.6-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
                      Breaks: libreoffice-style-human (>= 1:4.5~) but 1:5.0.6-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
 libreoffice-draw : Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:5.0.6-0ubuntu1) but 1:4.4.6~rc3-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
                    Depends: libcdr-0.1-1v5 but it is not installable
                    Depends: libdbus-1-3 (>= 1.9.14) but 1.8.12-1ubuntu5 is to be installed
                    Depends: libmwaw-0.3-3v5 but it is not installable
                    Depends: libodfgen-0.1-1v5 but it is not installable
                    Depends: libpagemaker-0.0-0 (>= 0.0) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 5.2) but 4.9.2-10ubuntu13 is to be installed
 libreoffice-gnome : Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:5.0.6-0ubuntu1) but 1:4.4.6~rc3-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
 libreoffice-gtk : Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:5.0.6-0ubuntu1) but 1:4.4.6~rc3-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
                   Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 5.2) but 4.9.2-10ubuntu13 is to be installed
 libreoffice-impress : Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:5.0.6-0ubuntu1) but 1:4.4.6~rc3-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
                       Depends: libetonyek-0.1-1 (>= 0.1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libmwaw-0.3-3v5 but it is not installable
                       Depends: libodfgen-0.1-1v5 but it is not installable
                       Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 5) but 4.9.2-10ubuntu13 is to be installed
 libreoffice-math : Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:5.0.6-0ubuntu1) but 1:4.4.6~rc3-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
                    Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 5) but 4.9.2-10ubuntu13 is to be installed
 libreoffice-pdfimport : Depends: libpoppler52 (>= 0.33.0) but it is not installable
                         Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 5.2) but 4.9.2-10ubuntu13 is to be installed
 libreoffice-writer : Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:5.0.6-0ubuntu1) but 1:4.4.6~rc3-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
                      Depends: libabw-0.1-1v5 but it is not installable
                      Depends: libetonyek-0.1-1 (>= 0.1) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libicu55 (>= 55.1-1~) but it is not installable
                      Depends: libmwaw-0.3-3v5 but it is not installable
                      Depends: libodfgen-0.1-1v5 but it is not installable
                      Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 5.2) but 4.9.2-10ubuntu13 is to be installed
                      Depends: libwps-0.4-4 but it is not installable
 libusbmuxd2 : Depends: libplist3 (>= 1.11) but it is not installable
 mysql-client-5.6 : Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 5.2) but 4.9.2-10ubuntu13 is to be installed
 mysql-client-core-5.6 : Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 5.2) but 4.9.2-10ubuntu13 is to be installed
 mysql-server-5.6 : Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 5.2) but 4.9.2-10ubuntu13 is to be installed
 mysql-server-core-5.6 : Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 5.2) but 4.9.2-10ubuntu13 is to be installed
 openjdk-8-jre-headless : Depends: util-linux (>= 2.26.2-4)
 python-pil : Depends: libwebp5 (>= 0.4.3) but 0.4.1-1.2 is to be installed
              Depends: libwebpmux1 (>= 0.4.3) but 0.4.1-1.2 is to be installed
 python3-pil : Depends: libwebp5 (>= 0.4.3) but 0.4.1-1.2 is to be installed
               Depends: libwebpmux1 (>= 0.4.3) but 0.4.1-1.2 is to be installed
 python3-uno : Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:5.0.6-0ubuntu1) but 1:4.4.6~rc3-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
 shim-signed : Depends: mokutil but it is not going to be installed
 thermald : Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 5.2) but 4.9.2-10ubuntu13 is to be installed
 thunderbird : Depends: libdbus-1-3 (>= 1.9.14) but 1.8.12-1ubuntu5 is to be installed
               Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 5.2) but 4.9.2-10ubuntu13 is to be installed
 uno-libs3 : Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 5.2) but 4.9.2-10ubuntu13 is to be installed
 ure : Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 5.2) but 4.9.2-10ubuntu13 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Answer (score 1):

There is some instruction on top of the error

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
```

Run this command, and try reinstalling the aptitude again.