# CUPS cannot be installed

Tags: apt, package-management, printing, dependencies

Today I ran an upgrade and I lost all printing.

Now I am trying to reinstall `hplip` and no luck at all
I get the message the CUPS is missing 
I attempt to install CUPS and get this:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
cups : Depends: libcups2 (= 2.1.3-4) but 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.2 is to be installed
    Depends: cups-core-drivers (>= 2.1.3-4)
    Depends: cups-daemon (>= 2.1.3-4)
```

Any ideas on how to fix this mess

I am using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: It looks like you installed a non-Ubuntu package.  Where did you get the package from?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove the "unmet dependencies error" about cups while installing a package?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/897348/how-to-remove-the-unmet-dependencies-error-about-cups-while-installing-a-packa)

Comment: Please take a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/897348/how-to-remove-the-unmet-dependencies-error-about-cups-while-installing-a-packa/898059#898059

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you've installed non-Ubuntu packages.  Ubuntu packages have the word "ubuntu" in the version.  You need remove the non-conflicting packages to return your system to the Ubuntu versions.

Firstly uninstall libcups2:

`sudo apt-get remove libcups2 cups-core-drivers cups-daemon`

Then tell apt to fix it:

`sudo apt-get -f install`

Then make sure everything else is in line:

`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`

If there are other non-Ubuntu packages that conflict, you'll get a similar warning.  If that happens, just repeat the process removing the conflicting packages and running `apt-get -f install`.

As for installing hplip, that's another question.

Comment: this completrely blew up my install, removed EVERYTHING, not only cups.  DO NOT FOLLOW THIS UNLESS YOU ARE READY TO REINSTALL UBUNTU.  Thanks for nothing

Comment: this is THE absolutely most irresponsible answer that i have EVER encountered on SO and it does not belong here without a MAJOR DISCLAIMER

Comment: @tony-gil Erm.  I've also done this more than a dozen times with success. I doubt that was what caused your reinstallation issue.  If your system has been damaged then I think it's more likely you uninstalled something else and ignored the big warnings that Ubuntu shows you before you uninstall core components.  CUPS is not a core component which is why this is safe and throws no warnings.

Answer (score 0):

and as some background, this thread was running on the Mint forum; (mint uses ubuntu); https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=51&t=242497&start=40

about nine posts down on this page is what worked but tudor has given you very careful instructions to follow;